# How to intercept and modify video frames from QCamera before they are saved to video file

Tags: c++, qt, video-processing

I'm trying to adapt the C++ non QML camera example in QT 5.11 so that it can intercept and add a visual time stamp to the video frames before they are written to the video file.

I want to achieve this without the use of QML.

There is a way to intercept the frames with QVideoprobe but the frame is passed in by const ref and so can't be modified.

Any suggestions except to use qml would be appreciated

Update - the typical way of doing this is to use QAbstractVideoFilter but all the examples I've found only show the filter being applied with QML so I'm initially looking to see how the filter can be applied to the QCamera pipeline in C++.

Comment: Have you tried to [map](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html#details) the pixel content of the QVideoFrame in memory with the 'map()' member function to manipulate its bits?

Comment: Not tried that  yet. From the Qt forum I get the idea that there is a method using QAbstractVideoFilter but the only problem is that it's done with QML and I can't see how to do it in c++ yet. Heres the forum conversation https://forum.qt.io/topic/97248/change-camera-example-to-add-a-time-stamp-to-recorded-video